# Cannot execute binary file: Exec format error when using clang++ cross-compiler to compike SFML

Tags: android, c++, cross-compiling, clang++, termux-linux

I'm have to run SFML C++ code on my Android device, terminal named Termux. I did build all libs for sfml, but can't cross-compile grop.cpp.

I run this command:

```bash
bash $NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android29-clang++\
   -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic   -I ~/SFML-2.5.1/include   -L ~/SFML-2.5.1/build/lib\
   -lsfml-system -lsfml-window -lsfml-graphics   grop.cpp -o gorp
```

But get output error:

```bash
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android29-clang++: line 4: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I target Android 10, architecture aarch64, supported ABIs: arm64-v8, armeabi-v7 and armeabi.

When I file the cross-compiler:

```bash
file $NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android29-clang++ /data/data/com.termux/files/home/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android29-clang++: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
```

When I file the cross-compiler as binary:

```
file /data/data/com.termux/files/home/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++                        /data/data/com.termux/files/home/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++: symbolic link to clang
```

When I file the actual actual binary:

```
file $(readlink -f /data/data/com.termux/files/home/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++)         /data/data/com.termux/files/home/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang-14: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, stripped
```

Comment: Ok it is a standard amd64 binary. Is your system an amd64 one? What does `uname -m`  gives?

Comment: @YSC The ```uname -m``` gives aarch64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You installed an LLVM/clang toolchain compiled for `amd64` (a/k/a `x86_64`) and try to run it on an `arm64` (a/k/a `aarch64`) system, hence the classical error:

```
cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

You need to install the proper toolchain for your system.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to install different toolchain.

Comment: Please help! I can't install toolchain for arm-64. Sorry for interrupting, but I installed android-ndk-r23b, but can't install toolchain!